# sdwebimage: Image in table cell gets stretched after initial load

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, caching, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage in my iPhone project and I use it to load images to my table cell.

The original downloaded image 150 * 150.
My placeholder image is 32*32 (required size)

First time, when the image loads, sdwebimage does a great job of re-sizing the downloaded image to match the size of the placeholder image (32*32). All good.

However, when I navigate back and then come back to the same page, the image gets stretched and fills the entire cell.imageView height. Is this normal behavior?

I need it to always retain the initial 32*32 size. Can you suggest how to do that?

**EDIT**: I found [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/83645-sizing-cell-imageview-when-using-sdwebimage-problem.html) where another user faces a similar issue (question open). The user also made a short [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmKsJ2AWrk8) to explain the issue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

try that for specific size at the cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
   UIImageView *addImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   [addImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourCellImageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]; 
   [addImage setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 78, 57)];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:addImage];
   [cell setIndentationLevel:8];
```

Answer (score 3):

***tldr***: If your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass has a `@property` `IBOutlet UIImageView*` called `imageView`, change your name to something else (such as `customImageView`) and it will work properly. Read the rest of the answer for why

I see nobody has answered that, and I wasted a whole week trying to find the solution to this, so here's what happened to me, and how to prevent it happening to you (thus fixing your problem).

I created a `CustomTableViewCell` which extends `UITableViewCell`.

I added `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;` to my custom cell.
Everything seems fine until now, right?

Except it is not.

`UITableViewCell` already has an `imageView` property. iOS 7 uses your property at first, but then when the Cell is being reused, the `UITableViewCell`'s **imageView** is used, therefore ignoring all of your constraints or previously defined fixed sizes.

iOS 8 always uses the image from `UITableViewCell`. so the problem is more obvious there. Previous iOS versions also had varying degrees of this problem, usually presenting very similar symptoms.

The solution? Either deal with the property `UITableViewCell.imageView` by yourself (add code for laying out the view) or create your own property with a **different name**, with which you can add constraints (in case you're using auto layout) on Storyboards or xib.

Comment: My god, you can't believe how much health you gave me with your answer, I could either feel stupid or thankful, either way if it wasn't for your answer I would have probably ended up doing something complicated such as setting the location of the imageview in code or something like that. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Ugh.. same. This should be a warning generated.  Sad thing is I think I just did the textLabel (same type of problem) two weeks ago and caught myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set proper content mode of the UIImageView

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate? I tried UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and it had no effect. I do not have a custom table cell.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change image size in SDWebImage.
use this call.

```
// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) { /*here you can change size of image */ }];
```